# Largest Number Drawn - Why are These Approaches Not Equivalent?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations, combinations

Here's the question:

Four numbers are drawn at random from a box of ten numbers 0, 1, ..., 9.  Find the probability that the largest number drawn is a six if the draws are made with replacement.  The answer, evidently, is

$$\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^4-\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^4$$

I understand this approach; since there are 7 possible numbers that are $\le6$ and 6 possible numbers that are $\le5$ (and since $\le5 \Rightarrow \le6)$, one can use the Difference Rule to obtain the probability that all numbers drawn are $\le6$ and at least one is $\gt5$, thereby ensuring that the largest draw is a six.

What I do not understand--and what is puzzling me quite a bit--is why the below approach is not equivalent:

$$\frac{K\cdot1\cdot7^3}{10^4} \tag*{for some natural number $K$}$$

I thought that I could use this method to tabulate the number of equally likely outcomes and divide by the number of all possible outcomes, but equivalence does not hold for any natural number $K$ (I first thought to try permutations but later realized the no $K$ works).  And, if there is some error in my reasoning for this second approach, is there a similar method that is equivalent to the first, correct approach?

Also, to make sure I understand, suppose I instead wanted to calculate the probability of a six, two fives, and a one (in any order).  Would that just be

$$\frac{4!}{10^4}$$

What about the probability of a six, two numbers in {3, 4, 5}, and a number in {1, 2}?

Thanks in advance.  This has me questioning my basic understanding of probability.

Comment: For a $6$, two $5$'s, and a $1$ (in any order), there are $10^4$ equally likely ways to draw $4$ numbers. Let's count the "favourables." The $6$ can be in any of $\binom{4}{1}$ places. For each choice, the locations of the $5$'s can be chosen in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways, and now it's over, except we could for symmetry note that the $1$ can be placed in $\binom{1}{1}$ ways. Total is $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$, which is $12$, not $4!$.

Comment: @André Nicolas: If you write it as $\dfrac{4!}{0!\,1!\,0!\,0!\,0!\,2! \, 1!\,0!\,0!\,0!}$ to include the lack of 0s, 2s, 3s 4s, 7s, 8s and 9s, I think it becomes more obvious how to generalise this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial calculation shows there are $7^4-6^4=1105$ combinations with largest number $6$.  This is not divisible by $7^3=343$, not even by $7$.  The error is that combinations with more than one $6$ get double counted in your approach.  The logical value for $K$ is $4$, which selects which die is the $6$.  $4 \cdot 343=1372$  But you are counting the ones with exactly two sixes, ${4 \choose 2}6^2=216$ twice, the ones with exactly three sixes ${4 \choose 3}6=24$ three times and the one with four sixes four times.  Subtracting off the extras gives $1372-216\cdot 1-24\cdot 2-1\cdot 3=1105$.  When a combination has more than one six, each six can be the distinguished one in your expression.